# Spacy \ Matcher \ set membership throws an exception

Tags: spacy

I use Spacy 2.7:
Following the [Set Membership](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1971) example:
I tried the below with the IN logic - simple list of words...

```
doc = nlp(SOME_TEXT)
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
pattern = [{'LOWER': {'IN' : ["i","you","we","they"]}}]
matcher.add("myPattern",None, pattern)
matches = matcher(doc) 
...
```

Get an exception

```
would:[{'LOWER': {'IN': ['i', 'you', 'we', 'they']}}] with index 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 85, in <module>
    matcher.add(key,None, curr)
  File "matcher.pyx", line 266, in spacy.matcher.Matcher.add
  File "matcher.pyx", line 99, in spacy.matcher.init_pattern
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Went to the open source file ([matcher.pyx](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/matcher.pyx)) - in line 99, not sure what is the bug, or maybe I used that incorrect..

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this was confusing – but the [GitHub thread](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1971) you're referring to is still only the *spec and proposal*, i.e. the planned implementation. The changes will hopefully ship with spaCy v2.1.0 (since some of the changes to the `Matcher` internals are not fully backwards compatible).

Comment: I don't want to overpromise, but definitely as soon as possible. We really want to get all the new features stable before the end of the year. (Getting the matrix multiplication fast, performant and system-independent across all platforms has been really difficult, so this is what's been holding v2.1.0 back.)